# Encryption issue

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish, encryption

I'm trying to write an encryption function in Netbeans but it's throwing up a very strange issue. It doesn't recognize the object passed to the doFinal(obj) function despite it having clearly been sent in the method's parameters:

```
private byte[] encrypt (Object obj, String pass) throws Exception 
{
    PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(pass.toCharArray());
    SecretKey secretKey =
        SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(keySpec);
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(secretKey.getAlgorithm());
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    byte[] encrypted = c.doFinal(obj);
    return encrypted;
}
```

Any ideas?

Removing the 3rd line results in the object being recognised again.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't recognize"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a method prototype for [`doFinal()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) that accepts `Object` -- try converting `obj` to a `byte[]` before passing it to `doFinal()`?